# How to disable CFileDialog Overwrite?

Tags: c++, mfc

I want to disable the overwrite from CfileDialog, not just the overwrite prompt but the function itself. is that possible?

```
CFileDialog fileDlg(FALSE, _T("pdf"), strFileGen, 
                    OFN_ENABLESIZING | OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST, 
                    szFilters);

if(fileDlg.DoModal() == IDOK)
{
    ...
}
```

maybe with a flag or overriding CFileDialog?

**EDIT**: when the file already exists I want to show a message saying that is not possible overwrite files and keep the 'Save as' dialog open so the user can change the name to a non exisisting name.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9707521.aspx